# How to setOnclick Listener to image in fragment

Tags: java, android-studio

I have image in my fragment. I want click on the picture and... for example change the fragment. I have found the same topic  [How to setOnclick Listener to button in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671745/how-to-setonclick-listener-to-button-in-fragment) but ClickListner does not work.
I have tried make the same code in Activity and onClickListner is work, but in the frame it does not work.

Below my code in the Fragment.

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment  {
ImageView imageView;
MyListner listner;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View getview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView) getview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listner.callback();
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
}
```

Below my interface

```
public interface MyListner {
public void callback();}
```

Below my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListner {
Fragment2 fragment2;
Fragment1 fragment1;
ImageView imageViewMain;
ImageView imageViewFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();//начало транзакции объекта
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment2);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

}

@Override
public void callback() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();//начало транзакции объекта
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment1);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}}
```

Please, let me know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are inflating your fragment's view twice. Instead of this you need to return the view which you have already inflated as a result of your `onCreateView` inside `Fragment2`.

Try changing

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
```

to

```
return getview;
```